# Hindi Font issue in RDLC report

Tags: asp.net, iis, download, rdlc

I want to print Hindi sentence in rdlc report. It is showing proper when I display report but when I
try to download the report in pdf format then Hindi sentence is changed in some blocks but it is showing correct in excel as well as in word file when I download it. This problem is occurring when I put the file in IIS even Hindi font installed in server, in local it is showing correct.
Please any one suggest me what correction I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that Hindi font is installed on your server and the asp.net may use the previous configuration for the report. I suggest you try restart the web server to see whether the host will apply the font changes.

More information about report configuration you can refer to this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms251661(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Hindi font already installed in web server also restart the web server many times but still facing same problem.